# How do I prevent labels going over each other in a for loop

Tags: c#, label

Okay, so I am picking up a text from a Textbox inside my form. From every letter inside that text I want to create a label, with its own fontsize and color. The problem is while I am doing a for loop through every letter in the text which creates the labels, the labels end up piling on to each other. And that results seeing only one letter.

How do I position the labels automatically next to each other, so that it resembles a normal text again, and preventing it piling up?

The reason for me wanting to create a label for every letter is that at a certain point I want the letters to move individually.

```
class MyGroup: Control
    {
        string s;
        private Random rnd = new Random();

    public MyGroup()
    {
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        this.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(126, 21);
        this.TabIndex = 5;
        this.TabStop = false;
        //this.Text = "groupBox1";
    }

    public void SetString(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void Fall()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {

            Label l = new Label
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y),
                ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)),
                Font = new Font("Arial", rnd.Next(7, 15), FontStyle.Bold)
            };
            l.Text += this.s[i];
            this.Parent.Controls.Add(l);
        }

        this.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

in Form.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EnteredText.Text) && EnteredText.Text.Length > 1)
            {
                EnteredText.Text.ToCharArray();
                groupBox1.SetString(EnteredText.Text);
                groupBox1.Fall();


            }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a text with more than 2 letters.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are setting the same location always.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how do I set the right location?, every letter needs to go next to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the body of "Fall" with this:

```
int nextX =  this.Location.X;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    Label l = new Label
    {
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(nextX, this.Location.Y),
        ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)),
        Font = new Font("Arial", rnd.Next(7, 15), FontStyle.Bold),
    };
    l.Text += this.s[i];
    l.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(l.Text, l.Font).Width;
    this.Parent.Controls.Add(l);
    nextX += l.Width;
}

this.Visible = false;
```

It will look like this:
[image: example]